# Using "LabelFor" and "ValidationMessageFor" with unique id of TextBoxFor from model

Tags: validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a `view` where I inject a `partialView` on a button click event (with ajax). My `partialView` contains a `SelectList` and a `TextBoxFor`. Now, each time I inject this partial I'll have a `DDList` and a `input` with same ids(also `LabelFor` and `ValidationmessageFor`) which is not what I want. I've tried to implement a way to construct that id dynamic(to make it unique) but it's not working so well.

***ViewModel***

```
public Ienumerable<Entity_DDList_Source> VM_DDList{get; set}//this gets populated in controller

[Required]
[Display(Name="Identity"]
public int id{get;set;}

[Required]
[Display(Name="Some details"]
public string details{get; set;}
```

***PartialView - classic way***

```
//this works well for only 1 generated model
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.id)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, new SelectList(Model.VM_DDList), datavalueField: "tableId", datatextField: "tableText")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.id,"")
```

**PartialView - what I've tried**

```
// like this, validation message is not being displayed though my select border turns to red
@{var idComposer = "id_" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "_" + DateTime.Now.Minute+ "_" + DateTime.Now.Second;}
@Html.Label(idComposer, "Label text here");
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, new SelectList(Model.VM_DDList), datavalueField: "tableId", datatextField: "tableText", htmlAttributes: new {@id=idComposer })
@Html.ValidationMessage(idComposer ,"")
```

How can I achieve a classic way of doing this but with unique ids?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all I've needed was to give same unique id to `name` as well:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, new SelectList(Model.VM_DDList), datavalueField: "tableId", datatextField: "tableText", htmlAttributes: new {@id=idComposer, Name=idComposer })
```

1.Be advised that after injecting the partial you need to **parse form validation** like this:

```
var $form = $("myForm");
$form.removeData('validator');
$form.removeData('unobtrusiveValdiation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
```

2.After parsing you'll need to perform a form validation as well, otherwise validators are not triggering like they should

```
$("myForm").valid()
```